# Generating large PDFs using Wkhtmltopdf/pdfkit + Python/Flask

Tags: python, performance, wkhtmltopdf

I have to generate a large PDF using a web app. The PDF is generated using a large data set of  email content for clients, right now it is written in php and what I am doing is basically looping over every item in the dataset, create an individual HTML page for each client and then add all those pages one by one to wkhtmltopdf via add page option.

This is obviously not very elegant and the php dies when the input is very big, like for 1000 clients. The idea behind this pdf is that we have to regularly send physical mails to our clients and we just want to create a big file, which we will then print and individually put them in envelopes and then mail them and stuff.

I'm now redoing this using Python instead of php. I am also not sure of what coding practice should I follow to make sure the PDF is generated in the fastest and most efficient manner.

Here are couple of options I thought about

#### Create one big variable

I'm wondering can I create a single big variable and then write the entire contents in one go into a html file and then use it to create pdf using wkhtmltopdf. However this would be a one really big variable and the RAM might go nuts.

#### Write to only one file

Not sure how will I be able to implement this, but maybe instead of creating a bunch of html files, I should just create one file and keep appending things in the bottom of that html file?

#### Stick with current concept?

Maybe the exact same programming design/concept will magically work well with Python
...?

Any or all of these options I have thought maybe be completely wrong and flawed though.

**EDIT:** Write to one file cannot work, since these mails have to be sent physically, I need to make sure every new content for each client starts from a new page. And if I write a single big file, there is no way I would be able to do it.

Comment: Why can't you use a single file? You can use page breaks, no?

Comment: That may be one good option I can look at-- if it will work: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=173

Comment: Then I suggest use a more robust tool! Reportlab or Weasyprint might do the job (Weasyprint may be your best call, since it converts html to pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as wkhtmltopdf is concerned, page breaking depends a lot on your content and your requirements. I need specific page breaks but I don't have a "1 content should always be one 1 page" limitation - if you do, don't bother with it. Also, if you have very specific styling rules, it might be difficult depending on what the styles are. The largest PDFs I've done with wkhtmltopdf are only 100 pages or so, so I can't comment on the sizes.

What I would with wkhtmltopdf do is format the content like this

```
<head>
    <style>
        .pb { page-break-before: always; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mail1" class="pb">...</div>
    <div id="mail2" class="pb">...</div>
    <!-- etc etc -->
</body>
```

This ensures that each email starts from a new page. Then feed that output to wkhtmltopdf using the desired styles and cli options and check if everything worked out as planned. This test should be very quick to do.

Additionally, if the HTML is Extremely simple and you can always rely on it being in a specific format (you could validate it with a simple XML schema) you could try iTextSharp and manually transform the HTML. I haven't done it and it sounds horrible, but might work for you - iTextSharp is quite fast.